# url redirect to page in external site

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

i have a page in my siteA
http://www.siteA.com/1987/title.html

i want to 301 redirect above page to a page in external site siteB as shown in example below
http://www.siteB.com/page/title3.html

I want to do this in htacess, not in php

I have tried

```
#redirect 301 /1987/title.html http://www.siteB.com/page/title3.html
```

this doesnot seem to work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.siteA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^1987/title\.html$ http://www.siteB.com/page/title3.html [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: thanks it worked i had to make other adjustments because of other rules i had in the htaccess already. thanks a lot for your help