# How do I redirect index.html to a Wordpress site?

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, migration

I am trying to move my html website over to a wordpress multisite and can't work out how to redirect the current homepage at www.essexmums.org to www.essexmums.com

I've been trying to use 302 redirects (before I do the 301s) but if I use:

Redirect 302 /index.html http://www.essexmums.com

or even

Redirect 302 / http://www.essexmums.com

I just get a message that it has caused the page to redirect too many times.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

edit: I'm not talking about a way of redirecting the whole site as I am setting up more specific redirects for those, I literally just want to redirect the current home/index page to the new one.

Comment: How are you issuing the redirect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Comment: Bejado - I tried adding 

Redirect 302 /index.html http://www.essexmums.com

and

Redirect 302 / http://www.essexmums.com

to the htaccess file

Comment: @Faegy : I'm not talking about a way of redirecting the whole site as I am setting up more specific redirects for those, I literally just want to redirect the current home/index page to the new one.

Comment: Well I'll update the duplicated link then, even with your edit there are so many posts handling the same issue. Have you even made a little bit of research before posting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [url redirect to page in external site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221344/url-redirect-to-page-in-external-site)

Comment: That one isn't what I mean either. I did search before but wasn't able to find something that was exactly what I was looking for. I will look again though, maybe I missed something. The problem seems to be to do with it being the index page. I can't just do a straight redirect from page to page, and I don't want to do a full site redirect because many of the pages will be different due to it going from html to wordpress

Answer (score 0):

IN case anyone else has this problem, I thought I would post my solution.

It turned out my problem came from my .com site being an add-on domain - it was redirecting because it was part of the .org. I've since moved it to a different host and the standard

Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.essexmums.com

works fine.